# Remove Item from GridView onClick from another Activity

Tags: android, button, gridview, android-activity

UPDATED my code..

I would like to remove an Item from my GridView ( Main activity ) when I click on the btn Button from the ( Day03 activity).

Here are my Activities :

public class Main extends Activity {

```
GridView gridView;
public static int deletePos;

static ArrayAdapter adapter;

static final String[] numbers = new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",
        "6", "7" };
static final String[] activities = new String[] { "Day01", "Day02",
        "Day03", "Day04", "Day05", "Day06", "Day07" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.grid);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid1);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String val = activities[arg2]; // arg2 is the index of item
            Class ourClass = null;
            try {
                ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.cahllenge." + val);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, ourClass);

            deletePos = arg2;
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

and the Day03 activity 
   public class Day03 extends Activity {

```
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int deletePos = Main.deletePos;
            Main.adapter.remove(deletePos);
            Main.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why do you need another activity? You can have long click listener and delete the items You can have check boxes with grid item and delete checked items. The other activity just to delete an item is not necessary unless you want to do something else

Comment: I have a sort of quiz in the Day03 Activity, i would prefer that when the user finishes it automaticlly remove the item from the GridView.

Comment: you can think of res-designing your app. The second one is really useless

Comment: Do you have an example please?

Comment: no i am not designing your app nor i have a similar code

Comment: I've updated my code.. can you suggest please?

Answer (score 0):

Hi First of all it's not good practice to delete the grdView item from another activity. anyhow if you want to delete it from another activity you can try this(Nothing is impossible). This may give you some trick to solve your problem.

create one deletegridViewItem(){} method in your MainActivity and from your Day03 Activity if you click the button then call deletegridViewItem() method. you need to manage which item should be deleted.Hope this will help you.

See this one edited one.....

hey try this might give you some clue... do not call 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after deletePos = arg2; just call your startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE); before this put you deletePos in intent using intent.putExtra-- next at your day03 activity onclick of button call finish method like this

```
 @Override
 public void finish() {
 // Prepare data intent 
 Intent data = new Intent();
 data.putExtra("put deletepos back to intent ");

 // Activity finished ok, return the data
 setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
 super.finish();
}
```

next in your mainActivity handle onActivityresult() method of intent and in onActivityResult method call remove method. and notify Dataset method...

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanna do this, and without using static I'd do it like this:

on your main activity create a onNewIntent()

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    int deleteMe = intent.getIntExtra('hasDeleted', 0);
    if (deleteMe > 0) {
        // delete numbers if it was List or update setAdapter with new numbers list
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and on the other activity after your finish onClick:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Day03.this, Main.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
intent.putExtra("hasDeleted", toDeleteNumber);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: ohhh before the notifyDataSetChanged add the delete code and variable that you wanna actually delete - updated code

Comment: I've did this but it does not work :
    @Override
 protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
     super.onNewIntent(intent);
     if (intent.getBooleanExtra("hasDeleted", false)) {
      adapter.remove(numbers);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
 }

Comment: ahh try putting the finsih after startactivity

Comment: ohh didn't notice you were doing it on an adapter, I haven't done that. I'd usually remove it from the numbers array and do a notifyDatasetChanged. Since numbers is array of strings you'd have to recreate it and do another setAdapter, or use a List<String> and numbers.remove(toDeleteStr);